# What is the order of records in a table with a composite primary key

Tags: postgresql, sorting, primary-key

In PostgreSQL, when a combination of multiple columns is specified as the `PRIMARY KEY`, how are the records ordered?

This is with the assumption that PostgreSQL orders the records in the order of the primary key. Does it?

Also, is the primary key automatically indexed in case of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This question makes the misguided assumption that the primary key imposes a table order at all. It doesn't. PostgreSQL tables have no defined order, with or without a primary key; they're a "heap" of rows arranged in page blocks. Ordering is imposed using the `ORDER BY` clause of queries when desired.

You might be thinking that PostgreSQL tables are stored as index-oriented tables that're stored on disk in primary key order, but that isn't how Pg works. I think InnoDB stores tables organized by the primary key (but haven't checked), and it's optional in some other vendors' databases using a feature often called "clustered indexes" or "index-organized tables". This feature isn't currently supported by PostgreSQL (as of 9.3 at least).

That said, the `PRIMARY KEY` is implemented using a `UNIQUE` index, and there is an ordering to that index. It is sorted in ascending order from the left column of the index (and therefore the primary key) onward, as if it were `ORDER BY col1 ASC, col2 ASC, col3 ASC;`. The same is true of any other b-tree (as distinct from GiST or GIN) index in PostgreSQL, as they're implemented using [b+trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree).

So in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
   a integer,
   b text, 
   PRIMARY KEY(a,b)
);
```

the system will automatically create the equivalent of:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX demo_pkey ON demo(a ASC, b ASC);
```

This is reported to you when you create a table, eg:

```
regress=>     CREATE TABLE demo (
regress(>        a integer,
regress(>        b text, 
regress(>        PRIMARY KEY(a,b)
regress(>     );
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "demo_pkey" for table "demo"
CREATE TABLE
```

You can see this index when examining the table:

```
regress=> \d demo
     Table "public.demo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 a      | integer | not null
 b      | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "demo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (a, b)
```

You can `CLUSTER` on this index to re-order the table according to the primary key, but it's a one-time operation. The system won't maintain that ordering - though if there's space free in the pages due to a non-default `FILLFACTOR` I think it will try to.

One consequence of the inherent ordering of the index (but not the heap) is that it is *much* faster to search for:

```
SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY a, b;
SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY a;
```

than:

```
SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY a DESC, b;
```

and neither of these can use the primary key index at all, they'll do a seqscan unless you have an index on `b`:

```
SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY b, a;
SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY b;
```

This is becaues PostgreSQL can use an index on `(a,b)` almost as fast as an index on `(a)` alone. It cannot use an index on `(a,b)` as if it were an index on `(b)` alone - not even slowly, it just can't.

As for the `DESC` entry, for that one Pg must do a reverse index scan, which is slower than an ordinary forward index scan. If you're seeing lots of reverse index scans in `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and you can afford the performance cost of the extra index you can create an index on the field in `DESC` order.

This is true for `WHERE` clauses, not just `ORDER BY`. You can use an index on `(a,b)` to search for `WHERE a = 4` or `WHERE a = 4 AND b = 3` but *not* to search for `WHERE b = 3` alone.

Comment: So, I should presume that lookups on the basis of leftmost column will be the fastest as compared to columns to the right(the columns I am talking about are all columns that form the primary key)?

Comment: @AbhishekJain Correct; using the leftmost column of the PK (or lookups that use both columns) will use the index, whereas using the rightmost column of the PK *only* won't be able to use the index at all. It can be helpful to create a second index on just the rightmost column if you need to do lookups on that a lot, or reverse the order of the primary key if you don't need to look the other column up alone.

Comment: @AbhishekJain You're welcome. I strongly advise you to become familiar with the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command, and with the `psql` command shell. Both will help you understand how PostgreSQL works much better, analyze how queries are executed, test different indexing strategies, etc. http://explain.depesz.com/ can be useful when trying to understand big and complex query plans, too.